# How does Chrome know what a centimeter is?

Tags: display

As stated in the question title, where do Chrome, other web browsers and programs like MS Paint get the information about how many pixels are needed to make up a physical centimeter?

As far as I know, such programs can't just assume a nominal pixel size as monitors with same resolution differ greatly regarding their active screen size. So for this to work, the display has to tell the computer not only how many pixels it has but also how big (in terms of physical size) its active area is.

I couldn't find any information about this question on the Internet, but my personal guess would be that the OS extracts this information from the EDID of the monitor.

But does anyone here know the answer to this question for sure?

Comment: it just assumes 1 inch  = 96 pixels = 72 pt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units

Comment: Really??? Couldn't imagine that to be honest. Thanks for the link. I didn't find anything useful to this question at all. But that would explain why changing the active screen size in the EDID (I'm working at a display company and tried it there) doesn't change the size of 1 cm on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chiliNUT pointed out in the comments, physical units in browsers don't necessarily match physical units in reality, but are instead tied to the size of a pixel (e.g. 1 in = 96 px) as stated in the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units

> Absolute length units
>   Absolute length units represent a physical measurement when the physical properties of the output medium are known, such as for print layout. This is done by anchoring one of the units to a physical unit, and then defining the others relative to it. The anchor is done differently for low-resolution devices, such as screens, versus high-resolution devices, such as printers.
>
> For low-dpi devices, the unit px represents the physical reference pixel; other units are defined relative to it. Thus, 1in is defined as 96px, which equals 72pt. The consequence of this definition is that on such devices, dimensions described in inches (in), centimeters (cm), or millimeters (mm) doesn't necessary match the size of the physical unit with the same name.
>
> For high-dpi devices, inches (in), centimeters (cm), and millimeters (mm) are the same as their physical counterparts. Therefore, the px unit is defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).